# How do I remove hard deposits from my glass shower door?

Tags: bathroom, doors, shower

I have a problem with regards to my frameless glass shower door because I don't usually clean it regularly. What happens is that the lower edge of the glass door is already very cloudy and is very coarse in texture. I tried to use some vinegar and water dipped with newspaper since I prefer using natural cleaners but it just won't work. Maybe it has accumulated too much that it can hardly be removed.

Do you have any other idea on what natural method to use for removing it? If possible,  I don't want to use the common glass cleaners sold on the market. That's the last choice for me.

Comment: It's probably limescale. Once you have removed it with appropriate limescale remover, the key is to wipe the door down with a cloth or a squeegee every time after a shower. This will prevent it building up again.

Answer (score 9):

Try using straight vinegar, right from a spray bottle.  It may work better if it's heated first.  Then try wiping with a used dryer sheet.

If that doesn't work, then you'll probably have to resort to something like [CLR](http://www.jelmar.com/CLRbasic.htm), at least for the initial cleaning.

Answer (score 7):

For major buildup of insoluble calcium and magnesium salts, including soap scum, citric acid is a better choice than acetic acid.

Unlike acetic acid, [citrate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citric_acid) is a pretty good [chelator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chelating_agent). It binds tightly to metal ions, and remains soluble. That allows the counterion of your soap scum complex free to dissolve too.

However, unlike vinegar, citric acid dries to a powder, so you have to clean that up after you clean up the soap scum. Also unlike vinegar, citric acid doesn't stink.
I use vinegar for light work, and citric acid for when things get nasty.

Citric acid is sold in the gricery store as coffee maker cleaner (check the label) and in coops and health food stores that sell bulk spices etc.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that the Mr. Clean Magic Erasers work well on this.

*I am in no way associated with this product, I've just had good experiences using it*

Answer (score 0):

Wayfaring Stranger has the right of it. Citric acid is far better at dissolving the calcium-magnesium-soap scum mix than vinegar.

Here in Dallas we have the worst limescale/soap scum buildup I've experienced. Having tried CLR, vinegar, and several other remedies, I was not prepared for how effective, easy, and odorless citric acid could be.

My suggestion for a cheap and ready source is a bathroom cleaner in a spray bottle (not the dry abrasive mix) that includes Citric Acid as the active ingredient (preferably 6% or more).

Answer (score 0):

I HAVE TRIED ALL OF THE REMEDIES AND THEY PROVIDE TERRIBLE RESULTS. The following recipe WILL absolutely work on the worst of all soap scum on shower glass doors & hard water spots & stains . You must go to the store and buy a new BAR OF LAVA HAND SOAP - not any other thing or  brand except LAVA BAR SOAP..
 Get the glass wet and proceed to rub that bar of soap on an area with a little bit of pressure until small amount of lather occurs. Wipe for about 30-60 seconds while keeping it wet. After 30-60 seconds of rubbing in one spot, stop and wipe it clean & dry and LOOK at it !
 It and say wow that guy knows all about this stuff! 
It will not scratch the glass. After you're done the entire door wipe it down with water , isopropyl alcohol or glass cleaner and then dry it . Now proceed to use a automobile wax of your choice to wax the shower glass door 2 times in a row .  If you want the absolute longest . Of time that this will last  you will have to buy a ceramic paint sealant located in the automotive wax section  wherever you shop  for  car products. You will love the long lasting results & you can thank me later about this bcuz  its the ONLY thing that works for soap scum on glass. This is one of the only ways to remove "etched in" water spots on automotive glass also.

Comment: Lava bar soap contains actual pumice which will almost certainly scratch the glass and any metal you use it on. It's not always apparent until you use it several times.

Answer (score 0):

Had this same problem for a long time and now I've solved it.

- Always squeegee the door after showering and:
- When a film develops spray the wet door with Ka-Boom, lightly wiping it with a plastic kitchen scrub pad. The pad won't scratch the glass and easily removes the lime-scale. You can buy it in most stores.

Answer (score 0):

Mix a combination of water, white vinegar, and dish soap (not dishwashing detergent) in equal parts into a spray bottle.

Gently shake it before use.

Spray it on the surfaces that you want to clean and let it sit for at least 10 minutes. The longer it sits, the less elbow grease you will have to use.

After sitting for the stated time, wipe and rinse off the surface.